# Double Trouble: number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length and sharing large matrices

Tags: r, loops, error-handling, statistics, regression

I am new to R and have an issue I hope I can get some input on. All tips and effort are appreciated, also to help me become better in asking questions on StackOverflow in the future.

I have a regression based optimization loop that compares prices at time `t` to to "payoffs" at `t+1`. The payoff of waiting is regressed on an underlying risk factor `price`. The underlying risk factor is simulated `P` times, following a geometrical brownian motion with drift. Running through the loop with high `P`, the error message

> number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

occurs, where this line:

```
V[ITM[as.logical(max.col(cbind(CV, ExV))-1)], t]
```

seems to have one extra value compared to:

```
SimFieldValue[ITM[as.logical(max.col(cbind(CV, ExV)) - 1)], t + 1]
```

while they are supposed to be of equal size.

Unfortunately the error message only occurs with high numbers of simulations (`P > 10000`) which makes for two large matrices (10000*14 + 10000*14) and I am unclear on how to share this.

I hope that:

1. Someone can tell me how to share large matrices/code so I share reproducible code.
2. Give me tips on how to handle the error message.

Underneath is the loop used, and some comments. If anyone is able to read the error from this code it would be brilliant.

```
N = 28
T = 28

optlf = 13
dt = T/N
P = 50000
r = 0.026
V = matrix(nrow = nrow(V1), ncol = optlf)
V[, ncol(V)] = pmax(SimFieldValue[, optlf+1], 0) 
V[is.na(V)] <- 0

for (t in (optlf-1):1) {

ITM = which(SimFieldValue[, t+1] > 0)
x = c[ITM, t+1]
y = V[ITM, t+1]*exp(-r*dt)
regr = splinefun(x, y, method = "natural")
CV = regr(x)

ExV = SimFieldValue[ITM, t+1]

V[ITM[as.logical(max.col(cbind(CV, ExV))-1)], t] = SimFieldValue[ITM[as.logical(max.col(cbind(CV,ExV))-1)],t+1]
V[,t] <- ifelse(V[,t]==0,V[,t+1]*exp(-r),V[,t])
}
```

`SimFieldValue` is a matrix P*14 with large "payoff" values.
`c` is the simulated risk factor of same size as `SimFieldValue`.

Comment: Not enough here for a reproducible example (i.e, where is `SimFieldValue` generated?). But check again the lengths: `nrow(V)` and `nrow(SimFieldValue)`.

Comment: Hello and thank you for answering @Parfait. nrow(V) and nrow(SimFieldValue) are P, number of simulations. It is the subsetting through ITM and max.col that makes them unequal, and I am not certain how that happens as ITM is fixed through each loop as the logical statement should be.

Comment: And: SimFieldValue is generated using c. It is the sum of cash flows generated through a fixed production rate and simulated prices. c then reflects an average of those simulated prices.

Comment: Check ITM's generation: `ITM = which(SimFieldValue[,t+1]>0)` which does not consider V. Also, verify the filtered lengths (notice length not nrow used): `length(V[ITM[as.logical(max.col(cbind(CV,ExV))-1)],t])` and same with SimFieldValue.

Comment: There is where the problem occurs @Parfait, given the numbers of simulations performed the loop stops at different periods (as I use set.seed for simulation). 
With P=50.000 the loop stops replacing V's values at V[,11], where:
length(V[ITM[as.logical(max.col(cbind(CV,ExV))-1)],11]) = 15719, and
length(SimFieldValue[ITM[as.logical(max.col(cbind(CV,ExV))-1)],12]) = 15718.

length(ITM[as.logical(max.col(cbind(CV,ExV))-1)]) = 15718.

I do not understand where the +1 in length in V[...] comes from.

Comment: How is `SimFieldValue` and `c` initialized? Please add to code or some working example that reproduces error.

Comment: I understand, and I am trying to find a way. So either:

1. I upload the parts of matrices, but the "write.table" capacity is too small - even for one row. The value is a result of 19 other loops and do not want to upload the whole code. Here, i need a way to upload the relevant area, where size restricts me from copying and pasting. I will try to find a package that allows me to share.

2. I send you the code per your preferred method.

Comment: I used the write.matrix() function in MASS to copy these. If this is OK, I will update the question to include these files. Here it is assumed P = 50.000, changed in main text

http://www.filedropper.com/c_14 <- C, no header, space separated

http://www.filedropper.com/simfieldvalue_1 <- header, space separated

Answer (score 0):

Would:

```
aa <- ifelse( ExV > CV, ExV, 0)

V[ ITM, t ] = aa

bb <- ifelse (V[, t] == 0, V[, t + 1]* exp( -r), V[, t])

V[, t] = bb
```

serve the same purpose as:

```
V[ITM[as.logical(max.col(cbind(CV, ExV))-1)], t] =  
SimFieldValue[ITM[as.logical(max.col(cbind(CV,ExV))-1)],t+1]

V[,t] <- ifelse(V[,t]==0,V[,t+1]*exp(-r),V[,t])
```

?